# Regioselectivity in nitration of a 1,2-disubstituted aromatic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, regioselectivity

For 1,1,4,4-tetramethyl-1,2,3,4-tetrahydronaphthalene:

[image: starting]

What would be the products following a standard nitration with $\ce{NO2+}$?

My reasoning is thus:
[image]

Since the substituent group is alkyl then it is *ortho-* or *para-* directing. But surely there are steric hindrance factors to be considered due to the bulk of the ring which would mean *para-* is favoured instead of *ortho*. However, when I try to draw out the structure it seems the arrows are *meta-* instead!

Answer (score 5):

The molecule is symmetrical so the two positions on the far side of the alkyl groups are exactly the same. Similarly, the two positions closest to the alkyl groups are the same. For the far positions, each one is *para* with respect to one alkyl group and *meta* with respect to the other. This is not a contradiction because *ortho*, *meta* and *para* are purely relative terms.

I suspect that you are right that substitution will mostly occur at the far sites. The directing effect of the alkyl groups is essentially the same for every site because they are all *ortho* or *para* to one group and *meta* to another. Therefore, the steric effect of the bulky methyl groups adjacent to the near positions will disfavour substitution there.

Answer (score 3):

Rewording my five-year-old comments into an answer:

The idea of "*meta*" or "*para*" is a bit different here, since you have not just one, but *two* alkyl groups. Being *meta* to one means *ortho*/*para* to the other, and vice versa. Since there are two substituents to start off with, you have to consider both their directing effects separately and add them up.

[image: Structure of starting material]

- The carbons labelled **a** are *ortho* to one alkyl group (stabilises the cationic intermediate a lot), but *meta* to another (stabilised a bit).
- On the other hand, the carbons labelled **b** are *meta* to one alkyl group (stabilised a bit), but *para* to another (stabilised a lot).

So, purely based on *electronics*, both positions are almost equally favoured. Now you turn to *sterics* to help you decide: as you said, **b** is favoured because it is less hindered.